# Recommended way of modeling resource membership in SQL

Tags: sql, data-modeling, access-control

Say I copycat Unix file system security groups in my DB: entities can be seen as files and visibility to those entities depend on which group a user belong to. Groups may contain users and other groups. Circular group membership is forbidden.

How to implement that in SQL?

Answer (score 2):

**You do not need to design any data model, just use existing patterns.**

Unix Security has complete security model. 
It has :

- Subjects (Users, Groups, Processes make accesses)
- Objects (Files, Directories, Services)
- Operations (Read, Write, Execute)

In Data Modeling world, we have some patterns to manage this type of permissions (Access Control Models).  
Context-based access control (CBAC) 
Data-centric security 
Discretionary access control (DAC)
Graph-based access control (GBAC)
Lattice-based access control (LBAC)
Mandatory access control (MAC)
Organisation-based access control (OrBAC)
Role-based access control (RBAC)
Rule-set-based access control (RSBAC)
Attribute-based-access-control (ABAC)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute-based_access_control

I offer **ABAC**: Attribute Based Access Control. Because of

1- ABAC is so complete and can answer all your requirements.

2- Unix Security has equivalence elements to ABAC.

ABAC basic elemets are:

- **Subject**: who is demanding access to an information asset
- **Action** : that the Subject (User) wants to perform
- **Resource** : identifying the information asset or object impacted by the action

google and find more details. 
https://www.axiomatics.com/attribute-based-access-control/